# Problems with while loops and methods (won't exit loop properly)

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I am writing a small fallout text based game, and I am having trouble with while loops.

The main way of getting input a second time is to send them back to the beginning of the method (each room in the starting vault is a method, as seen below:

```
    public static void elseoverseeroffice()
    {            
        command = in.nextLine();

        if (command.equals("look around") || command.equals("l") || command.equals("look"))
         {
            overseeroffice();
         }
```

This is a small example of what I am doing.

I have it so that when a player inspects a terminal, it enters into a loop of the terminal: (the while loop is down the bottom, the other text is there for context. delay(); just delays the printing out for cool effects)

```
    public static void overseerterminal()
    {
                delay();
                  System.out.println("================================================");
                  delay();
                  System.out.println("=        VAULT 9 OVERSEER TERMINAL             =");
                  delay();
                  System.out.println("================================================");
                  delay();
                System.out.println("\n   > VAULT 9 OVERSEER INSTRUCTIONS");
                  delay();
                  if(elevator_sys==false)
                    {System.out.println("   > ACTIVATE ELEVATOR SYSTEM");}
                  else
                    {System.out.println("   > DEACTIVATE ELEVATOR SYSTEM");}
                  delay();
                  if(saferevealed==false)
                    {System.out.println("   > REVEAL SAFE");}
                  else
                    {System.out.println("   > HIDE SAFE");}
                  System.out.println("   > EXIT");
                  delay();
                  delay();
                System.out.println("\n  TYPE YOUR SELECTION");

               while (!command.equals("vault 9 Overseer Instructions") || !command.equals("VAULT 9 OVERSEER INSTRUCTIONS") || !command.equals("ACTIVATE ELEVATOR SYSTEM") || !command.equals("activate elevator system") || !command.equals("REVEAL SAFE") || !command.equals("reveal safe") || command.equals("exit") )
               {
                       command = in.nextLine();
```

I have a number of options to do in the terminal, all which loop back into the terminal. The last command that you can type in to this terminal is

```
                    else if (command.equals("exit") )
                    {
                        System.out.println("You shut down the terminal.");
                        elseoverseeroffice();
                        break;
                    }
```

I have a break there to stop the loop, but if it is before the overseer office, it doesn't run, and if I have the break and then elseoverseeroffice(); outside of the while loop, what happens is if I type in a command in the room that is not a valid one, it puts the player back into the terminal loop.

Here is some copy and pasted text from the command line:

```
You press a button on the terminal, and it springs to life, displaying the     need to input a password.
Type the password.
excalibur
================================================
=        VAULT 9 OVERSEER TERMINAL             =
================================================

> VAULT 9 OVERSEER INSTRUCTIONS
> ACTIVATE ELEVATOR SYSTEM
> REVEAL SAFE
> EXIT

TYPE YOUR SELECTION
exit
You shut down the terminal.
look around

**Overseer's Office**
This small important looking room is lit by a circular light.


A central round desk sits in the middle of the room.

There is an entrance to your east.
what
what
INVALID COMMAND
I am back in the terminal
INVALID COMMAND
exit
You shut down the terminal.
see
```

I don't know what is happening. It returns me back to the terminal method only when I am in the room. I can make a mistake in another room (each room is a method, as they are individual) and it will say "You can't do that".

Any help? I know this is long but if you need any more code, just tell me what and I will comment it. I don't want to upload the whole program.

P.S
This is also happening in a later part of my program. This whole thing runs on the player health being greater than 0, and I have a room that is instakill for the player.
If the player enters into another while loop in a different room and THEN goes into the instakill room, they are not killed. Perhaps I Should have that leading to an end game method, I am unsure.

Thanks guys, first post here.

Comment: first thing , either you must make the exit statement in lower letters or you need to change while(str.equalsIgnoreCase("String to match")

Comment: Yeah I just looked at my code... I had while (.... || command.equals("exit"), instead of || !command.equals("exit")

Answer (score 1):

Should be

```
while ((!command.equalsIgnoreCase("vault 9 Overseer Instructions") && 
  !command.equalsIgnoreCase("activate elevator system") && 
  !command.equalsIgnoreCase("reveal safe")) || command.equalsIgnoreCase("exit") )
```

Comment: Why not reduce that to half by using `equalsIgnoreCase()`?

Comment: Or even shorter: `! command.matches("(?i)vault 9 overseer instructions|activate elevator system|reveal safe")`

Comment: You missed `exit`. ;-)

Comment: Thank you for this everyone!